Why can’t Chrome connect to devices on my local network in macOS 15.2?
I'm on macOS 15.2.
I guess I have somehow clicked "may not discover" devices on the local network for Chrome. Now, Chrome can't open any website on my local network and reports "address unreachable". I can still access all these sites in Safari and even chrome if I use my VPN.
Through research, I found Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Local Network -> Chrome.

Chrome is listed there nine times, but the slider is enabled for each instance.
I'm stumped here. Anything I can do?

Update: Okay, I'm making some progress here.
If I open the Chrome application directly ("Show package contents" -> "Contents" -> "MacOS" -> "Google Chrome") and rename the executable, everything works just fine. Interestingly enough, this adds yet another entry to the "local network" tab under privacy and security. Research yielded that another entry gets added if you ever upgrade Chrome while it's running.
Sadly, renaming the Application package has no effect.
Thus, it seems to be fair to make the following assumptions:

My privacy/security profile for Chrome is somehow broken, since it has "local network access" disabled permanently - no matter where I actually put the slider.
I cannot get the "Allow access" dialogue to spawn again, thus any application named "Google Chrome" has local network access disabled permanently.
Reinstalling Chrome doesn't help.
Either Chrome or MacOS has an issue with recognizing that a new build of Chrome is not a new application. This leads to the many duplicate entries.

Sadly, there doesn't seem to be a solution right now:

It doesn't seem to be possible to reset "Privacy and Security" as a whole.
It doesn't seem to be possible to delete the security profile for Chrome.


As of macOS 15.2, I am sadly not aware of any way to manually alter the list of applications shown in System Settings → Privacy → Local Network.
If the list becomes filled with orphaned apps or is otherwise behaving in unexpected ways, the only workaround I know of is the method below. This will completely reset the list, so be aware that this will cause apps you had previously approved to prompt again for access. Consider that VPN tunnnels and other network extensions will need to be set up again.
Steps

Start up your Mac in Recovery mode

Disable SIP by opening a Terminal and typing csrutil disable

Reboot

Delete the 2 .plist files below:
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.uuidcache.plist


Reboot your Mac again for the changes to take effect


Once you confirm that the list is clean and the problem is fixed, you should re-enable SIP by booting into Recovery mode again and typing csrutil enable into the Terminal.

Nice work. If you boot to recovery, and navigate to those files you might be able to skip the csrutil invocations. Also, I wonder if some form of tcccutil would reset the database more directly while the system runs?

@bmike: From what I've gathered from research, "local network" is not managed by tcccutil: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/766270

I can confirm this works. However this method also deleted other config from my laptop, such as my wireguard tunnels. Proceed with caution!

Very nice research on the DTS engineer post there @Fang I would expect the implementation here to change based on all I read there. So glad we have this workaround for now until things shake out.

I had the same issues on a Macbook Air M1 and de-activating, rebooting, and then re-activating all Google Chrome entries shown at "Local network" followed by another reboot didn't help.
Yesterday I activated the Firewall under "Network" but a reboot also didn't solve the problem.
Earlier today, I deactivated the Firewall again, and after a reboot, the popup window asking if Chrome can scan for devices showed up.
This time I agreed and was finally able to access my local devices again.
A bit strange and I honestly don´t understand it but I'm glad that it works again.
